# Rails 4. Ошибка No route matches [PUT] "/client/orders"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Пытаюсь создать процесс оформления заказа в интернет магазине. Пользователь открывает корзину (объект Cart), в которой видны товары (объекты LineItem). Вместе с этим сразу же создается объект Order, в который будет записан готовый заказ.
    Так выглядит Client::CartsController:

```
def index
  if @cart.nil? || @cart.line_items.count == 0
    empty_cart
  else
    @order  = Order.new
    @cart   = @cart.line_items.includes(:item)
  end
end
```

Так выглядит сама корзина:

```
= simple_form_for [:client, @order], url: client_orders_path, method: :post, action: 'create' do |f|
  - if user_signed_in?
    = f.input :user_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: current_user.id }
  %table.table.table-hover.table-bordered#cartTable{ 'data-attr_id' => session[:cart_id] }

  Здесь в таблице описание заказов

  = f.input :address
  = f.input :phone_num, as: :tel
  - if user_signed_in?
    = f.button :submit, 'Оформить заказ', class: 'btn-primary'
```

Далее, по нажатию кнопки "Оформить заказ" форма должна уходить в контроллер Client::OrdersController, но я вижу такую ошибку:

```
No route matches [PUT] "/client/orders".
```

Вот файл routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

scope 'admin' do
  devise_for :admins, :controllers => {
    :confirmations        => 'admin/admins/confirmations',
    # :omniauth_callbacks   => 'admin/admins/omniauth_callbacks',
    :passwords            => 'admin/admins/passwords',
    :registrations        => 'admin/admins/registrations',
    :sessions             => 'admin/admins/sessions',
    :unlocks              => 'admin/admins/unlocks',
  }
end

scope 'client' do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {
    :confirmations        => 'client/users/confirmations',
    # :omniauth_callbacks   => 'admin/admins/omniauth_callbacks',
    :passwords            => 'client/users/passwords',
    :registrations        => 'client/users/registrations',
    :sessions             => 'client/users/sessions',
    :unlocks              => 'client/users/unlocks',
  }
end

namespace :admin do
  root 'items#index'
  resources :items
end

namespace :client do
  root 'items#index'
  resources :orders do
    resources :order_items
  end
  resources :carts, :items do
    resources :line_items
  end
end

root 'client/items#index'
```

Мне непонятно, почему вызывается метод PUT в данном случае. Сейчас видимо для того, чтобы не было ошибки, ему не хватает id, но мне нужно вызвать экшн create. Как нужно задать форму, чтобы не было данной ошибки и запрос уходил в OrderControoler#create?

Comment: У вас, кажется, в разметке отступы поехали. Перепроверьте.

Comment: Покажите сгенерированный html, а именно тег `<form ..... >`
Вы передаете action, url -- это все лишнее, хелпер simple_form_for распознает по объекту, create это или update. То же самое с урлом.

Comment: Да, действительно неверно вставил сюда haml разметку, подправил.
Сгенерированная форма:
`<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form new_order" id="new_order" action="/client/orders" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">`
Да, я сначала пробовал без action и url, но ошибка таже. Может быть дело в том, что я генерирую форму в одном контроллере (carts), а далее хочу, чтобы она обрабатывалась в другом (orders)?

Comment: Это форма на `create`, сабмитится, похоже, другая. Нет, форма генерируется не в контроллере, а в представлении (view), и связь с контроллером у него минимальна.

Answer (score 1):

Выполните команду

```
rake routes
```

Посмотрите, какие пути доступны для /client/orders
Для PUT путь должен быть с указанием идентификатора :id

```
/client/orders/:id
```

У вас же путь не привязан к заказу с конкретным идентификатором id

```
No route matches [PUT] "/client/orders".
```